# Change link_to text with :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to be able to change the [x] to [o] after link_to is clicked. Most articles explain how to update a div outside of link_to and I yet to get this to work in this case. Since I am not pushing dynamic data to the client, is there a simpler, built-in rails 3 approach to simply change the text in link_to?

```
<%= link_to '[x]', final_path(t.id), :remote => true  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
link_to '[x]', final_path(t.id), :remote => true, onclick:"javascript:$(this).val('[o]')"
```

Comment: I know, but I was referring to a simple why via the server (async)